# How to confirm that my AWS Lambda function is updated successfully?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-lambda

The last words I can read from intellij AWS console after hitting update Lambda function is, "Waiting for function to stabilize". There is never a confirmation message that my lambda function is updated in the cloud. Nor can I find my current function id in AWS console (in this case it is `cc3988579bd7cb089e84d6bb09066c24`).

```
Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file /Users/xxx/...
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template
sam deploy --template-file /Users/xxx/...

Waiting for function to stabilize
```

[image]

Comment: If you look at the console, you should see field "Last updated" or similar. You can see timestamp there

Comment: Are you using the Java runtime API and IntelliJ to build the Lambda function?

Comment: Yes, it is the intellij AWS Toolkit plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any keyword relates to "update" from within the function. Then I found it in the function list. (Inspired by Oleksii Donoha, thank you)

[image]